# Run python script on arduino

Tags: python, audio, arduino

i have a python script to slice wav file using start, end time. I want to execute this in arduino. can i run this directly into arduino? or if not, can you suggest idea how can i do this?

```
import wave
import pygame
import time
import sys


def slice(infile, outfilename, start_ms, end_ms):
    width = infile.getsampwidth() #Returns sample width in bytes
    rate = infile.getframerate()  #Returns sampling frequency
    fpms = rate / 1000 # frames per ms
    length = (end_ms - start_ms) * fpms
    start_index = start_ms * fpms

    out = wave.open(outfilename, "w")
    out.setparams((infile.getnchannels(), width, rate, length, infile.getcomptype(), infile.getcompname()))

    infile.rewind()             #Rewind the file pointer to the beginning of the audio stream
    anchor = infile.tell()      #Return current file pointer position
    infile.setpos(anchor + start_index)  #Set the file pointer to the specified position
    out.writeframes(infile.readframes(length)) #Write audio frames and make sure nframes is correct


if __name__ == "__main__":

       slice(wave.open("song1.wav", "r"), "out.wav", int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))

       pygame.mixer.init()
       pygame.mixer.music.load("out.wav")
       pygame.mixer.music.play()
       while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
             continue
```

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is far beyond the capabilities of an Arduino. A Raspberry Pi could do that.

Comment: and "no", an arduino can not execute a python file. therefore you need a python-interpreter.

Comment: can i use c++ for this? for that i need c++ library . can i import c++ library into arduino?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an arduino mega you could take a look at [PyMite](http://playground.arduino.cc/CommonTopics/PyMite).

For arduino uno there was a post ([Is there a way to "compile" Python code onto an Arduino (Uno)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114916/is-there-a-way-to-compile-python-code-onto-an-arduino-uno)), about compiling python for arduino and in it there were mentioned two projects [pyMCU](http://www.pymcu.com/overview.html) and the other one in developement by a SOer, you could give it a try

But as they said, porting it to C++ is the easier way

Comment: @ Mr. E , can i run python file like this ? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzPUqBP4KQpjcWNHLWVOQjktR0U/view?usp=sharing